# how to compare array element of one array with elements in another array in bash?

Tags: bash

I have stored some strings in array1, lets say

```
array1[0]=apple
array2[1]=orange
```

and array2 contains

```
array2[0]=apple
array2[1]=mango
```

I want to loop through each element and check if they match. I tried using this condition inside loop but it didnot work

```
if [ "$array[i]" = "$array2[j]" ]
```

Comment: I don't see a loop in your posting. Complementing the answer given by Socowi: If you prefer the array access syntax you are using, you could consider switching to zsh (which also would make the quotes unnecessary). Bear in mind that array indexing in zsh starts with 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the elements of an array in bash you have to use `${array[i]}` instead of just `$array[i]`. Because the `[` cannot normally be part of a variable name, bash interprets `$array[i]` as `${array}` followed by a literal `[i]`.

By the way: https://www.shellcheck.net/ would have found this error.

Comment: thanks, the problem was in syntax, it solved my doubt.